# How to delete the file

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I'm trying to delete files that are more than six months old.  This is my code.  It recognizes the files, but does not delete.

```
 Private Sub DeleteOldBackup()


        'deletes files older than six months from backup
        Try
            For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In New IO.DirectoryInfo(BACKUP).GetFiles()
                If DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, Now, fi.CreationTime) > 6 Then
                    fi.Delete()
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Call WriteToErrorLog("DeleteOldBackup", ex)
            SendErrorEmail("Long Term Report Storage failed in DeleteOldBackup")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Any exception? Permission issues?

Comment: The `ex.Message` in your code should help a lot

Comment: I hate to state the obvious, but if you put a breakpoint on `fi.Delete()` and run the debugger does it ever get there?

Comment: no. that's kinda what I'm asking.  Is there something wrong here that is preventing that? The first file that it reads should get deleted but it doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateDiff subtracts from the second date the first date. Passing the highest date in the first position returns a negative number.

Just swap the positions of the two dates

```
 If DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, fi.CreationTime, Now ) > 6 Then
```

Keep also present that this calculation is wrong. For example

```
Dim d1 = new DateTime(2014,1,1)
Dim x = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, d1, Now)
Console.WriteLine(x)
```

The code above prints 6 but actually there are more than 6 months between the first of january and today. Perhaps you should use DateInterval.Day and check against something like 180 days to have a better approximation of 6 months

Comment: I think this is the answer, although there's nothing wrong with using DateDiff on month if what you're looking for is calendar months that have passed.